# Cannot run RabbitMQ via Docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

What do I do wrong?

[image]

run as command
docker run -d --name rabbitmq_awr -p 5672:5672 -p 5673:5673 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management

but http://localhost:15672/ didn't launch in browser

log below

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: check the logs
`docker logs 18e`

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

1. Make sure that your radditMQ instance is running by doing `docker ps.`
   and if it is listed in the running containers.
2. Find out on which IP it is running on by using `docker network inspect`
3. Get that IP and launch it into your browser instead of localhost.

**Second**

If your container is not listed when you run `docker ps`, find out from the logs it issues using `docker logs <container-name or id>` whats causing the container to fail.